# Deleting a dynamically created userform after extracting data

Tags: vba, userform

I have a userform that is being created through code to input quantities of tools into an array to then use elsewhere in the worksheet. The problem I am running into is every time I run the code a new userform is created. I would like to avoid this as each userform that gets created will only be used one time.

When 'Continue' on this form is pressed a new userform is created:

[image: When 'Continue' on this form is pressed a new userform is created]

This form is then created with the name 'UserForm1':

[image: This form is then created with the name 'UserForm1']

This is the code that I am using to create the userform:

```
Sub CreateFormToolQty()
Dim objFrm As Object
Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim txtBox As MSForms.textBox
Dim label As MSForms.label
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim line As Long
    
    Set objFrm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
    
    objFrm.Properties("Width").value = 2
    
    'create label that prompts user to input quantities
    Set label = objFrm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    label.Caption = "Enter quantity of selected tools:"
    label.Height = 18
    label.Width = 130
    label.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
    label.Top = 2
    
    'loop to create labels and text box for each selected tool
    j = 0
    
    For i = 1 To formNoTools
        Set label = objFrm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        label.Caption = arrayTools(j)
        label.Height = 24
        label.Width = 66
        label.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
        label.Top = 12 + i * 18
        label.Left = 12
        
        Set txtBox = objFrm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        txtBox.Name = "txtTool" & i
        txtBox.Height = 18
        txtBox.Width = 36
        txtBox.Left = 78
        txtBox.Top = 12 + i * 18
        
        j = j + 1
        
        If i > 600 Then Exit For
        
    Next i
    
    Set btn = objFrm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        btn.Name = "OkButton"
        btn.Left = 12
        btn.Top = 36 + formNoTools * 18
        btn.Caption = "Ok"
        btn.Height = 24
        btn.Width = 54
        
    With objFrm.CodeModule
        line = .CountOfLines
            .InsertLines line + 1, "Sub " & btn.Name & "_Click()"
            .InsertLines line + 2, ""
            .InsertLines line + 4, "End Sub"
    End With
            
    Set btn = objFrm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        btn.Name = "CancelButton"
        btn.Left = 78
        btn.Top = 36 + formNoTools * 18
        btn.Caption = "Cancel"
        btn.Height = 24
        btn.Width = 54
    
    With objFrm.CodeModule
        line = .CountOfLines
            .InsertLines line + 1, "Sub " & btn.Name & "_Click()"
            .InsertLines line + 2, "Unload Me"
            .InsertLines line + 4, "End Sub"
    End With
    
    With objFrm
        .Properties("Height").value = formNoTools * 18 + 100
        .Properties("Width").value = 160
        .Properties("Caption").value = "Tool Quantities"
    End With
    
    VBA.UserForms.Add(objFrm.Name).Show
    
End Sub
```

The code for the 'OkButton' is still a work in progress so I have not put it in yet.
Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not have a pre-created form with OK and Cancel buttons, and add the labels and textboxes as needed?  You can add the required controls when the userform is shown - no need for the Designer method.  That way you also don't need to add code to manage the form control events.

Comment: I can give that a shot. I didn't know it was an option to be honest. I'm just starting to learn how to do this stuff so it's all very new to me. Would I still be able to have the size of the userform change with more labels and text boxes?

Comment: Yes you can set the size when the form loads - eg `Me.Width = 200: Me.Height = 400`  Some previous posts here: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+dynamic+userform+site:stackoverflow.com